# downloading some file automatically as soon as you connect to a device via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, download

I am creating an app that will connect to a device via `Bluetooth` depending on a particular `UUID`, and i am successful in that.

Now my next task is as soon as I connect to that device it should download a file automatically once I am paired with the device. The other device just has to accept my connection.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP or GOEP (over OBEX) profile?

It's not clear from your post but I'm going to assume you have control on both devices.

Have one device act as the FTP server and put the file to be downloaded in a designated FTP directory on that device.

The other device can then connect and download that file using the FTP profile over Bluetooth.

Comment: I will read about it and will revert back, but as of now seems good.
and yes i am having command on both devices, its like one device will be my server(not a portable device) and i will have to code it just once. and then my other device(my android phone) will connect as a client and will download the file automatically which will contain a URL to go to.

Comment: hey, is it anyhow possible to download the file automatically, because after i had setup i will not have access to the server and the file to be downloaded is in server folders only.\

Comment: If you have an application that inquires and connects to the server, it can then use the FTP profile to download the file, I guess.